# Ruby loop jump to previous item

Tags: ruby, loops

When I'm looping through an array

```
@arr.each {|x|
  x.increment #x is an instance of my class that implements the increment method
  if !array_valid? #array_valid? is my method with specific logic
     #make 'x' previous item in array and continue
  end
}
```

is it possible to return to the previous item instead of continuing with the following? This way the current item would be looped over once again until `!array_valid?` is false.

For instance, let's say that the current x is at the index 5 in the array, `!array_valid?` is true, so the loop returns to the index 4, increments a value there, `!array_valid?` is false, the next index is 5, `!array_valid?` is false, the next index is 6, ..., until the end of the array.

Or is there any other loop in Ruby that would allow this behaviour easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this, using array indexing:

```
i = 0
while ( x = @arr[i] ) do
  x.increment
  if array_valid?
    i += 1 
  else
    i -= 1
  end
end
```

If you have a complex rule for iterating through a structure, sometimes it is simpler to fall back to index manipulations, there isn't always a clever Ruby-ish way to abstract it. Although in this case there *might* be a way to manipulate the iterator in the `.each` loop, I haven't checked to rule it out.

Comment: It seems you misunderstood me. To be concrete, I'm doing a sudoku solver based on this simple algorithm http://www.math.cornell.edu/~mec/Summer2009/meerkamp/Site/Solving_any_Sudoku_I.html and when there is latter something invalid I need to step back and try with another value at the previous index.

Comment: @Ondrej Janacek: Your statement "This way the current item would be looped over once again until `!array_valid?` is false" is what tripped me up  . . . I read from it that you wanted to repeat the current item. I will adjust this answer to match your comment here

Comment: All right, the second solution seems reasonable. I thought about something like this. I guess I was just curious if Ruby has something more powerful to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the ["Simple [Sudoko] Solving Algorithm"](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~mec/Summer2009/meerkamp/Site/Solving_any_Sudoku_I.html) you referenced.  Listen carefully and you will hear it whispering, "Use recursion! Use recusion!".  You might want to try  something like this (some is pseudo-code) or consider using recursion when you are facing a similar problem in future:

```
def solve_it
  initial_state = < [], {}, nil or ? >
  outcome, solution = solve_next([0,0], initial_state)
  if outcome == :solved
    puts "I solved it! I solved it!"
    puts "Here's my solution!"
    <print solution>
  else
    puts "No solution exists"    
  end
end

def solve_next(current_cell, state)
  (1..9).each do |v|
    if current_cell -> v is valid
      new_state = state + current_cell -> v
      (return :solved, new_state) if current_cell == last_cell ([nrows-1, ncols-1])
      i, j = current_cell
      new_current_cell = (j < ncols-1) ? [i,j+1] : [i+1, 0]
      outcome, solution = solve_next(new_current_cell, new_state)
      if outcome == :solved
        updated_solution = solution + current_cell -> v
        return :solved, updated_solution
      end
    end
  end   
  return :no_solution
end
```

Comment: Wow, you tried to help even when an answer is accepted. That is really nice of you. Although I'am glad for your help, I would like to solve it my self. Not to mention that your answer actually do not answer my question and it could be probably deleted by mods for violating SO rules.

Comment: Ondrej, I just wanted to show you and other readers how a problem like this one lends itself to a recursive solution.  I just outlined out the structure; implementation would require some work.  The nice thing about recursion is that it allows one to be concerned only with the current "state", not how one got to that state.

Comment: Cary, just because a question has an accepted answer doesn't mean other users can't also provide an answer. While your question may have helped you, truth be told there are thousands of future visitors who may come across this and be helped by the information here, not just what helped you. Please see [What is an accepted answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Hope this helps clarify!

Comment: I agree, @jmort253, but did you mean to direct your comment to Ondrej?

Comment: @CarySwoveland - Yes, my apologies, that is directed at Ondrej. :)  Time for me to get off the computer for awhile.